# Validate method does not see dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to have custom validation on Vote resource

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base

  include HasUser  
  belongs_to :votable, polymorphic: true   

  validates :votable, :vote_field, presence: true 
  validates :user_id, uniqueness: { scope: [:votable_id, :votable_type] } 
  validate :vote_permission

  def vote_permission
    errors.add(:permission, 'denied') if self.vote_permitted?
  end

  def vote_permitted?
    self.user == self.votable.user   
  end  

  def down?
   self.vote_field == -1 
  end

  def up?
    self.vote_field == 1 
  end
end
```

In my specs I'm getting error 
**Vote should validate that :user_id cannot be empty/falsy
     Failure/Error: self.user == self.votable.user**
Where I am wrong? What should I do to make this work?

This helped

```
  def vote_permitted?
    if votable.present?
      self.user == self.votable.user 
    else
     false
    end  
  end
```

but is it a right desigion? Sorry for my English

Comment: can you share complete stack trace of error and spec which is raising this error?

Comment: Have you tried adding `presence: true`?